# Do we have $C^\infty \cap \mathcal{O}_C' = \mathcal{S}$ and/or $C^\infty \cap \mathcal{S}' = \mathcal{O}_M$?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

We define the following traditional function spaces from distribution theory.

- $\mathcal{S}$ the space of rapidly decreasing smooth functions.
- $\mathcal{S}'$ the space of tempered distributions, dual of $\mathcal{S}$.
- $\mathcal{O}_M$ the space of slowly increasing smooth functions (i.e., the function and all its derivatives are bounded by a polynomial).
- $\mathcal{O}_C'$, the space of rapidly decreasing distributions, i.e. distributions $u \in \mathcal{S}'$ such that $u * f \in \mathcal{S}$ for every $f\in \mathcal{S}$. (We have that $\mathcal{F}\ \mathcal{O}_C' = \mathcal{O}_M$ with $\mathcal{F}$ the Fourier transform on $\mathcal{S}'$.)

> Now are my questions. Do we have the following equalities between sets:
>   $$C^\infty \cap \mathcal{O}_C' = \mathcal{S},$$
>   and
>   $$C^\infty \cap \mathcal{S}' = \mathcal{O}_M?$$

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What about $f(x)=\exp(ie^x) \in C^\infty \cap L^\infty \subseteq C^\infty \cap \mathscr S'$? The derivative $f'(x)= ie^x \exp(ie^x)$ grows very fast.

Comment: Right. Good and simple counterexample. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Goulifet What book did you read that from?